# Qemu: Emulating Raspberry pi with Buster OS on MacOS X (CLI works, but blank screen)

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, qemu, raspberry-pi-zero

Trying to figure out why I have a blank screen for my Raspberry Pi running Buster OS in Qemu but do have a function CLI?  Here's what I run:

```
    $ qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -hda ./raspbian-buster-full.qcow -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 -dtb ./versatile-pb.dtb -kernel ./kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -append 'root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw' -no-reboot -serial stdio
```

And end up with a few failure messages:

```
    vpb_sic_write: Bad register offset 0x2c
    ...
    Welcome to Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)!
    systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
    systemd-fstab-generator[41]: Mount point file is not a valid path, ignoring.
    ...
    [FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
    See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
    ...
    [FAILED] Failed to start rng-tools.service.
    See 'systemctl status rng-tools.service' for details.
```

Not sure what `vpb_sic_write: Bad register offset 0x2c` relates to or the `[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.` But I'm OK with `[FAILED] Failed to start rng-tools.service.` because I think `rng-tools` are related to random number generation, and I don't need that.

At first I thought the lack of display was due to no console specified in the append option, but in the boot script I did see the following, which leads me to believe that was not the problem.

```
    clocksource: arm,sp804: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
    sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
    Failed to initialize '/amba/timer@101e3000': -22
    sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
    Console: colour dummy device 80x30
    console [tty0] enabled
```

Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: That looks like an error message buffer, not a boot script... everyone needs rng.  How is a packet supposed to know when to fire?

Comment: Also. Try the `-display sdl` flag.  You may need to recompile qemu with SDL support.  Also also. Try `console=ttyAMA0` to try and match output.